# reuse table alias in another select

Tags: sql, select, alias

I have a sql statement:

```
select id from table1 t1, table t2 
where.....
order by ( select count(owner_id) from t2) ASC;
```

What I want to do here is to select the id of the item whose owner has least number of items.

Is this possible? If not, what I can do to achieve to goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you not just `order by t2.id asc`?

Comment: @Alex K. actually, I want to verify something else in the select statement used by order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention what SQL you're using but you can do this, or something similar, in PL ( and My I believe ); I'm assuming you're linking table 1 and 2 on `id`; I haven't ordered by the count(owner_id) alone as this will always be the same value. Obviously partition by whatever you want to get the correct count you're after.

```
select id
  from ( select t1.id, t2.ct
           from table1 t1
              , ( select id, count(owner_id) over ( partition by id ) as ct
                    from table2 )  t2 
          where t1.id = t2.id 
          order by t2.ct ASC )
       ;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the topmost select?

Comment: The OPs question only had `id` in the select so I did the same @Abe. There's no reason other than that and it may not be required, depending on what the OP is doing.

Comment: "I'm assuming you're linking table 1 and 2 on id" -- your SQL code only uses `table1`. The OP's code contains two tables names `table1` and `table` respectively.